# SCSS files not loaded in a laravel vue 3 project using vite and inertia

Tags: laravel, sass, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I am trying to use the materio vue template in my laravel breeze application(laravel+vue3+vite) which I downloaded from this [link](https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-vuetify-vuejs-admin-template-free/demo/). After making some necessary changes, I got the project to run without any errors but the template's style are not loaded. In the resources/js/@core/scss/index.scss file, all the scss imports using @use are not loaded hence the styles are not applied in my project. How can I solve this. Here is the github link to the project ([project link](https://github.com/zakayohaule/metrio)). Any help would be much appreciated.

Screenshot of the homepage [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the same admin template from [here](https://github.com/themeselection/materio-vuetify-vuejs-laravel-admin-template-free).

Everything is functioning properly on this template. Have you compiled it using yarn dev? Please refer to this installation [guide](https://demos.themeselection.com/materio-vuetify-vuejs-admin-template/documentation/guide/laravel-integration/installation.html) for more information. You can also try downloading the latest package from the GitHub repository.

Let me know if you still face the same issue.